# im trying to connect mysql with nodejs but have error

Tags: mysql, node.js

im trying to connect mysql with nodejs but have error
i think its a mysql problem not nodejs .
this is the error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\MySQL\server.js:23:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

also i dont have mysql in my task manager
i think i did something but i got error before it disapeared

my js code is

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      port     : 3306,
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'philipthe1',
      database : 'todo'
    });
    connection.connect();
    connection.query("select * from items",(error,res,fields)=>{
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
        else{
            console.log(res)
        }
    })
    connection.end();
```

Comment: There is your answer "i dont have mysql in my task manager". Mysql is not running, therefore there is nothing listening on port 3306. Hence why you're getting the ECONNREFUSED error

Comment: i know thats the problem

Comment: Start mysql then

Comment: how ??? i tryd mysqld in /bin of sql but nothing happens

Comment: How did you install mysql?

Comment: from download page i installed community version

Comment: figured it out thanks

Comment: Awesome. What was the issue?

Comment: my server was  closed ps should i delete question

Comment: i am now geting a new error Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client ps no upgrades are available

Comment: figured that out to from old question

Answer (score 0):

It is a mysql error, cuz it says you cannot connect to db.

Can you add the code in which you're trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to restart mysql by doing windows key and r on keyboard then services.msc
then it gave option start server
the docs for it is in mysql docs under restarting server